# Rendering Dynamic Data retrieved from External Server with Tanstack Table or AG Grid

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, ag-grid, nuxt3, tanstack

I have this `working` piece of code in my `nuxt3` app ...

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p v-for="user in users" :key="user.id">{{ user.name }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      users: {},
    }
  },
  async mounted() {
    this.users = await $fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
  },
}
</script>
```

I would like to `recast/refactor` the code to use `Tanstack Table` or `AG Grid` to `show/render` the `same data`. In order to do that, what's the replacement for this line of code (in above code)? ...

```
<p v-for="user in users" :key="user.id">{{ user.name }}</p>
```

Thanks